# How can we add a New Row When user clicks Add New Row in WebGrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

I faced a problem when user clicks on "Add New Row" needs to add a Row in the bottom of the web grid using MVC3 Razor.I have done this requirement by showing the Modal PopUp Dialog and adding the record in DB adding the new record at the last when pagination is enabled.But client requires to add a row at the bottom of the table and give privelege to enter data in the input fields and save.

Can we do this when the paging the enabled in a Web grid?Do we have any inbuilt property to add a Row?

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/223/adding-a-new-row-in-the-razor-webgrid

Answer (score 3):

I found in an article that we can't create a Row in WebGrid.So I have done using jQuery like this

```
$('#btnCreateUser').click(function () {
            var newRow = "<tr> <td></td> <td><input type='text' id='tbNameDyn'/></td> <td> <input type='text' id='tbAgeDyn'/></td> <td><input type='checkbox' id='tbResultDyn'/></td><td><input type='submit' name='submitButton' value='Save Row' id='btnSaveRowDyn' onclick='DynButtonClick();'> </td></tr>";
            //  $('#webgrid > tbody:last').
            $('#webgrid tbody:last').append(newRow);
            $('#btnSaveRow').removeAttr('disabled');

        });
```